# how can I access the methode/variable of one class from another class without instantiating it or subclass in c++?

Tags: c++

I tried to pass the reference of one class to another, it seems fairly complicated cause I have to edit all the files in which the class is involved.

I tried to set the variable as static member, but it seems pretty ugly.

I can subclass another class. But is there other ways rather than subclassing it?

```
class A
{
func1(){};
};
class B
{
func3()
{
    //how can I call func 1 without instantiating class A and subclass A?

};

};
```

Comment: Make it a static method ?

Comment: if you want to call `func1` without an object of `class A` , then why did you make it a member function in the first place?

Comment: Static member functions are really global functions, just inside the class's namespace. That is, they don't have a 'this' pointer and therefore can't access any other members of the class (except for other static members).
-----seems I still have to declare static variable?

Comment: If you want to call a member function, you either have an instance of that class or you are calling a static function. Otherwise something is wrong with your object model. Maybe your class A as a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: @T.F.: "*they don't have a 'this' pointer and therefore can't access any other members of the class*" You realizes that the `this` pointer has to point to an *instantiation* of the class, right? Which means you have to *have* an instantiation of a class in order to call a function that requires a `this` pointer. Otherwise, where would it come from?

Comment: @NicolBolas yea, that's right. I think I actually should describe my question in a different way. I'm searching a way to call method of one class in another one without sub-classing and "substantiating one class in another one".

Comment: @T.F.: Where do you expect to get the class instance from? If a function does not have access to an `A` instance, and cannot create one, you cannot call a method of `A`. Just like if you have a function `foo(int)`, and your function doesn't have access to an integer and cannot create one, you cannot call that method. Your problem sounds very XY. Can you explain the *actual* problem you're encountering that makes you want to do this?

Comment: @NicolBolas I created two classes, they will be all instantiated in another class. I hope these two classes can exchange information between them like calling function of one class in another. I can possibly instantiate one class in another. But I just want to leave these two class as "virtual class" without being created as instance before the final step. It seems writing one of them as another's sub-class is the only option.

Comment: @T.F.: Classes are not real things. They're *prototypes*. They're like cookie cutters. The cutter itself isn't a cookie; it makes cookies. Classes don't have data; *instances of classes* have data. Therefore, classes cannot talk to each other and share information between them; only *instances of classes* can do that.

Comment: @NicolBolas so basically one class is driver, another class is part of the GUI program, they will be all instantiated in a bigger GUI class. I want to call some of the driver function in the part of the GUI program.(which I will also do in other part of the GUI program) I can write the GUI class as the sub-class of the driver class, but it looks rather actually ugly to do so. Also I think I have to avoid instantiating driver class in GUI part class, cause different GUI part exchange information inside this driver class.

Comment: @T.F.: Then the "part of the GUI program" needs to be given access to the particular driver instance it's trying to talk to. If the "part of the GUI program" doesn't have a driver instance, then someone needs to tell it *which* driver instance to talk to. It can't talk to all of them. And if there's only supposed to ever be one driver instance, then make it a global singleton or something. Your problem seems to be caused by your architecture, your class design.

Comment: @NicolBolas that was very clearly explained, I think I figured it out. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 2):

> how can I access the methode/variable of one class from another class without instantiating it or subclass in c++?

You can not "*access the methode/variable of [a] class from [anywhere] without instantiating it*", if the method/variable is non-static.

Non-static member variables are contained within an instance. Without an instance of the class, there is no instance of the member variable. Without instantiating the class, you don't have an instance. So, you must instantiate an object to access the member variables of the instance.

Likewise, non-static member functions can only be called on an instance. Without an instance, you cannot call the member function. Without instantiating the class, you don't have an instance. So, you must instantiate an object, to access the non-static member functions.

Note that when you instantiate a class that inherits another class, you also instantiate a base class sub object. So, you cannot avoid instantiating the object even through sub classing.

Static member functions and variables can be used without an instance of the class, just like free functions and global variables. But of course, just like the free functions, static member functions can not access non-static members of an instance through the `this` pointer, because they're not associated to any instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can define friend class B in class A

```
using namespace std;

class B;

class A{
 private: 
  static void myfunc()
  {
    cout << "Hello";


  }

 friend class B;

};

class B {

 public:
  void hellofromA() {
    A:: myfunc();
  }
}; 

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  B x;

  x.hellofromA();

}
```

it involves either making it global or static, with friend class, you can make the function hidden from other classes

Comment: How does this help?  you still need an instance of an `A`.

Comment: no, from B, you can call func1, just like func1 is defined in B

Comment: I think you have to instantiate at first.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating classes, if you don't tell those functions inside the class are public, private or protected... c++ will put them as private.

You should make something like this:

```
    class myFirstClass {
    public:
        void function1();
    };

    class mySecondClass {
    public:
        myFirstClass A ;          // Create the object.
        A.function1();            // Now you can use this function.
        void function3();
    };
```

Comment: sorry, but imho `firstClass` is a quite bad name for an instance

Comment: The OP is trying to avoid having to create an instance of `myFirstClass`

Comment: _"When you are creating classes, if you don't tell those functions inside the class are public, private or protected... c++ will put them as private."_ Only when you create those classes using the `class` keyword. If you create them using the `struct` keyword instead then C++ will put them as public instead!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for that information!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is possible to call `func1` without an object of `class A` (that is what you want if I understand correctly) it would be better to structure the code like this:

```
void func1(){};

class A {
    void callFunc1() { func1(); }
};
class B {
    void func3() { func1(); }
};
```

However, if the assumption is not correct, and `func1` needs to be a member function of `class A`, then there is no way to call it without an instance.